# How to send transactions Infura + Web3.js + WalletConnectProvider

Tags: web3js, transactions, web3-providers, walletconnect

I want to initiate transactions using the following stack. However, Infura doesn't support `web3.eth.sendTransaction(tx)` because it requires the server to hold private keys. Here is a link to how it should work https://example.walletconnect.org/ and the repo https://github.com/WalletConnect/walletconnect-example-dapp.

So far this is what I have.

```
        const provider = new WalletConnectProvider({
            infuraId: "**************",
        })

        await provider.enable();

        const web3 = new Web3(provider);

        web3.eth.getAccounts().then((account) => {
            console.log("kk", account)
            setAccount(account)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("Failed to get accounts", err)
        })

        web3.eth.getBalance(account[0]).then((balance) => {
            setAccountBalance(balance)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("ayre", err)
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the contract function and that will work. For example if you  want to initiate an ETH transaction and you have the function `buy()` in your contract used for purchasing goods, you can call it with your contract instance:

Declare the contract instance:

```
const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(contract.abi, contractAddress)
```

Use the contract instance to call your function

```
instance.methods.yourContractFunction().send({from: accounts[0],value:price}).then("confirmation",(confirmation) => {
        console.log(confirmation)
      }).catch("error", (error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
```

Comment: I thought contracts are used for ETH tokens, also do I have to write solidity code for this?

Comment: I suggest you check  out this tutorial: https://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/web3-js-intro. It will  explain how to use contract functions and call them with web3.

Comment: I want to be able to send a transaction without using Ethereum-tx and I don't have he wallet's private keys. Check out my follow up question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/112153/how-to-send-usdt-or-usdc-tokens-using-web3-js-without-eth-tx